# how to replace values in a data frame that is already constructed (pandas)?

Tags: python, replace, pandas, dataframe

So, an ideal data frame would consist of all possible combination of factors `c1` and `c2`:

```
>>> c1 = ['a','a','b','b']
>>> c2 = list('xy'*2)
>>> val = np.random.rand(4)

>>> df_ideal = pd.DataFrame({'c1':c1, 'c2':c2, 'val':val})
>>> df_ideal
 c1 c2       val
0  a  x    0.277162
1  a  y    0.324269
2  b  x    0.156026
3  b  y    0.435033
```

However, I don't know before hand if any of the combinations will be missing, so I could end up with a data frame like this (combination `b x` is missing):

```
>>> df
  c1 c2       val
0  a  x    0.277162
1  a  y    0.324269
3  b  y    0.435033
```

If this happens, then I would like the missing combination to receive a `val` of 0.

```
>>> df_desired
   c1 c2       val
0  a  x    0.277162
1  a  y    0.324269
2  b  x    0
3  b  y    0.435033
```

One way to do this would be creating a data frame containing all combinations of `a`,`b` with `x`,`y` and assign 0 to all of them:

```
>>> df_empty
   c1 c2  val
0  a  x    0
1  a  y    0
2  b  x    0
3  b  y    0
```

Then, after reading the data frame `df`, I could tell pandas to insert the available elements in `val` in the appropriate rows of `df_empty` (`0.277162` in row corresponding to `a x`, `0.324269` in row corresponding `a y` and `0.435033` in row corresponding to `b y`). This would give me the `df_desired`.

Is it possible to do this in pandas?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your data is really indexed by the `c1` and `c2` values.  If so, you should make your data structure a Series with a MultiIndex and then use that to insert the values you need.

```
c1 = ['a','a','b','b']
c2 = list('xy'*2)
val = pandas.Series(0, index=pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(c1, c2)))
>>> val
a  x    0
   y    0
b  x    0
   y    0
dtype: int64
```

Then:

```
>>> val.ix['a', 'x'] = 100
>>> val
a  x    100
   y      0
b  x      0
   y      0
dtype: int64
```

If you have multiple columns of values (not just one `val` column), you can make a DataFrame using a MultiIndex in the same way.

Comment: Not really. Sometimes it may be row 9 other times row 3. It depends on what the user fails to respond. The combination of columns is always the same though, i.e., all possible combinations of (a b) with (x y) with (G1 G2). That's why I thought of creating an empty data frame and then tell pandas to fill it in with the values that the user provides.

Comment: @HappyPy: You need to provide more information about what you mean by "the values that the user provides".  How do *you* know which row you want to replace?  If the user provides an item in row `x`, you can use `df.ix[x, 'val']` to insert a value at that position in the table.

Comment: @HappyPy Are you looking to *append* rather than replace?

Comment: @Andy Hayden: How would you do it with append? If, when "df" is read, it happens to contain "a  x  G2  0.277162", then this should replace "a  x  G2    0" in the empty data frame I'd created. Would append have this effect?

Comment: @Andy Hayden: I have edited the whole question from scratch. Does it make more sense?

Comment: @BrenBarn: Thanks, that's closer to what I wanted. However, I don't have to assign the values to 'val' myself, because I'll get them from a file (which will result in a data frame like "df" in my example above). So basically I just need a function of some sort that goes through the indexes of "df" (e.g., 'a' 'x'), extracts its corresponding value from 'val' and replaces 0, in "df_empty" that corresponds to that index (e.g., 'a' 'x'), with that value.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a left merge between df_empty and df, then fillna with 0:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1':['a','a','b'], 'c2':['x','y','y'], 'val':[0.277162, 0.324269, 0.435033]})
df_empty = pd.DataFrame({'c1':['a','a','b','b'], 'c2':['x','y','x','y']})
df_desired = pd.merge(df_empty, df, on =('c1','c2'), how='left', copy = True)
df_desired = df_desired.fillna(0)
print df_desired

   c1 c2       val
0  a  x  0.277162
1  a  y  0.324269
2  b  x  0.000000
3  b  y  0.435033
```